# How can I open all the links of a bookmark folder on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

On Chrome Microsoft Windows I can do:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that today. The Chrome for windows is different from the Chrome app - the latest is lighter, since mobile devices usually have less hardware power...

Comment: On Android, the process is not as quick as on PC. You need to go to Bookmarks, open the bookmark folder, select the bookmarks one by one, select the 3-dot, then select Open in new tab.